# Error trying to send sms by php

Tags: gammu

I installed gammu in linux and I can send sms using the shell command. But when I add the command in a php page I get the following error:

```
$phone = 3588459717;

echo shell_exec ('gammu sendSms TEXT '.$phone.' -text "test msg"');
```

Error opening device, it does not exist.

Comment: thank you, I copu the file .gammurc from user folder to php file folder as gammurc, give all permissions to this file, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the web server is running as different user and Gammu running under this user does not see your configuration file and/or does not have permissions to open the device.

Answer (score 0):

php process under apache Server, runs as a user with permission **www-data:www-data**
try to ad permission, please start console as root user and add permission **dialout** to user www-data.

```
id www-data   
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)

usermod -a -G dialout www-data

id www-data   
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data), 188(dialout)
sudo service apache2 restart
```

after apache restart, run your php script